# What is the shortcut for opening a flashing program?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

When someone sends me an IM or a installation program finishes, the icon of the program starts flashing orange. But I'm tired of clicking on them and aiming with my mouse - Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a "orange flashing" taskbar window (program)?

[image]

Comment: ALT-TAB, but it you've got lots of apps that could be more work than moving your mouse.

Comment: On a 4K screen you can really push many apps to the taskbar.. usually around 40/50 I think, and indeed alt+tab could be more work in some situations. I'm more looking for a shortcut like WIN+[1,2,3..0], except for apps that notify me of something.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there is no default or built-in function to do this. Any solution is likely to depend on third-party apps.

A few Google searches did not find any results for such a system.